# Path 2.0 menu animation xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

I've downloaded Menu Path 2.0 from https://github.com/yourabi/PathMenuExample/downloads.
The "Add" button make expanding & collapsing an array of menu items (animated menu drawn along a curve).

[image]

But I want to make those button expanding/collapsing in a straight line.

Here is code
**ExpandableNavigation.m:**

```
- (void) expand {
transition = YES;

[UIView animateWithDuration:self.speed animations:^{
    self.mainButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( 45.0 * M_PI/180 );
}];

for (UIView* view in self.menuItems) {
    int index = [self.menuItems indexOfObject:view];
    CGFloat oneOverCount = self.menuItems.count + 50<=1?1.0:(1.0/(self.menuItems.count-1));
    CGFloat indexOverCount = index *oneOverCount;
    CGFloat rad =(1.0 - indexOverCount) * 90.0 * M_PI/180;
    CGAffineTransform rotation = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( rad ) ;
    CGFloat x = (self.radius + self.bounce * self.radius ) * rotation.a;
    CGFloat y = (self.radius + self.bounce * self.radius ) * rotation.c;        

    CGPoint center = CGPointMake( view.center.x + x , view.center.y + y);
```

Comment: I'd like to know how to make the expanding icons into a vertical line to present the icons with a line of text next to them.

Comment: I also want to know :D

Answer (score 0):

For anyone needs in future, change the angle with your desired angle of transformation.

```
    - (void) expand {
transition = YES;

[UIView animateWithDuration:self.speed animations:^{
    self.mainButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( 45.0 * M_PI/180 );
}];

for (UIView* view in self.menuItems) {
    int index = [self.menuItems indexOfObject:view];
    CGFloat oneOverCount = self.menuItems.count + 50<=1?1.0:(1.0/(self.menuItems.count-1));
    CGFloat indexOverCount = index *oneOverCount;
    CGFloat rad =(1.0 - indexOverCount) * 90.0 * M_PI/180;
    CGAffineTransform rotation = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( rad ) ;
    CGFloat x = yourDesired_X; //should be same for all menu items
    CGFloat y = (view.frame.size.hieght+8.0)*index; //Y should be increasing or decreasing for every item       

    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(x , y);
```